# Android opengl transparency issues

Tags: android, opengl-es, background, transparent

I'm rendering 3 different polygons with the same smiley texture.
The texture is a yellow circle put on a transparent background.

My issue is that if i put a smiley that is drawn earlier in front of another that is drawn later it will make the one drawn later transparent where the early ones background is transparent.

Well a picture is worth a thousand words!
See Image of the problem and the smiley png [here](https://sites.google.com/site/chrsin/stackoverflow/android-opengl-transparency-issues).

The issue doesn't occur if i put the lastly drawn smiley in front of the other, so the issue seems to be related to the drawing order. Anyone have any input?

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
    //Textures a loaded here See next section for the implementation of loadTextures method on the polygon class.
    loadTextures(gl, context);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glClearColor(.5f, .5f, .5f, 1);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
    if(h == 0) {
        h = 1;
    }

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    float ratio = (float) w / h;
    gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 30);
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, lookEyeX, lookEyeY, lookEyeZ, lookCenterX, lookCenterY, lookCenterZ, lookUpX, lookUpY, lookUpZ);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {      
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    draw(gl);
}
```

Implementation of the loadTexture method

```
public void loadTextures(GL10 gl, Context context) {
    if(bitmap == 0) {
        return;
    }
    //Get the texture from the Android resource directory
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(bitmap);
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        //BitmapFactory is an Android graphics utility for images
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    } finally {
        //Always clear and close
        try {
            is.close();
            is = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    //Generate one texture pointer...
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textureIDs, 0);
    //...and bind it to our array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[0]);

    //Create Nearest Filtered Texture
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    //Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    //Clean up
    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

Comment: Never tried blending combined with depth test... what about removing the depth test completely? As far as I know there are a some pitfalls if you want transparancy in OpenGL ES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even transparent fragments are written to the depth buffer. Your options are:

1. Disable the depth buffer - either don't write to it or disable the depth test.
2. Enable the alpha test so that transparent fragments are rejected. e.g.:

   GLES10.glEnable( GLES10.GL_ALPHA_TEST );

   GLES10.glAlphaFunc( GLES10.GL_GREATER, 0 );
3. Sort your geometry and draw the quads in back-to-front order

Comment: I was wondering about alpha-testing... wouldn't he still have to draw in back-to-front order? Or does it do some sort of boolean AND with the depth test?

Comment: Effectively, yeah. If a fragment fails the alpha test, it is discarded and never makes it to the depth or frame buffer

Answer (score 1):

Turn off depth-testing. The missing pixels of the rearmost smiley are missing because the foremost smiley has filled the depth buffer.

Obviously you will need to draw your smileys in the correct order, rearmost first.

I guess what you'd *ideally* want is for your depth buffer to accumulate alpha values rather than Z values... don't know how possible that is. :-(

Comment: Turning off depth testing doens't solve the issue since that makes me see the mouth of the smiley through the other smiley. I guess i will have to control the order in which i draw the polygons. Thx for your answer!